# roslyn analyzers raising warnings which are later removed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

I have an analyzer based on the default template for analyzers.
My problem is that when a do a **full rebuild**, some (*but not all*) the warnings appear on the error list.

When I open the files, the warnings start vanishing as the analyzer is re-executed on the open file. **Eventually all the warnings disappear**.

Am I registering these analyzers incorrectly. Ideally I only want them to execute once the code model is loaded properly.

Any suggestions on how to improve this would be great.

```
    public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(
            this.HandleClassDeclaration,
            SyntaxKind.ClassDeclaration);
    }
```

This code analysers documentation (in this case) on the class declaration.
It reports a diagnosic when the Xml documentation nodes don't exist.

```
    private void HandleClassDeclaration(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        // THE CHECK IN MY ANSWER BELOW GOES HERE...
        var declaration = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
        {
            var hasDocumentation = declaration.HasDocumentation();
            if (!hasDocumentation)
            {
                var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(this.Descriptor, declaration.Identifier.GetLocation());
                context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using this code to find the documentation.

```
    public static DocumentationCommentTriviaSyntax GetDocumentationCommentTriviaSyntax(this SyntaxNode node)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (var leadingTrivia in node.GetLeadingTrivia())
        {
            var structure = leadingTrivia.GetStructure() as DocumentationCommentTriviaSyntax;

            if (structure != null)
            {
                return structure;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to **analyse documentation in Roslyn**, this little **check is needed**.

```
    // <summary>
    // check that the compiler is in a build mode that enables documentation analysis.
    // it's not clear when this is off, but command line builds, and full rebuilds
    // seem to have it turned off from time to time.
    // </summary>
    internal static bool IsDocumentationModeOn(this SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        return context.Node.SyntaxTree?.Options.DocumentationMode 
               != DocumentationMode.None;
    }
```

Comment: This reflects the "generate an XML doc comment" option in your project file. Maintaining legacy behavior, it's the case that if you aren't generating one we don't parse them, since previously we let you get away with bad syntax there.

Comment: I have noticed that whilst the number of false positives has decreased since checking this option, the behavior is still not quite correct.
I still have scenarios where if I do a full rebuild, there are false warnings displayed. As soon as I open the file, they disappear.

Answer (score 1):

can you switch your error list to build only view and see whether the warning is still there?

if warning is still there, that means the warning is generated by command line build. if the warning goes away once you opened the document, that means live analysis thinks there is no issue. and due to this difference between build and live analysis, the issue could happen.

if that is the case, it would be a bug in roslyn. (more specifically, bug in compilation option between live analysis and command line build - build inside of VS is also command line build with slightly different options)

Comment: the warnings are no longer being raised in error.
the check below fixed most of them. I think the last few were due to a bug in my analyser / fixer where the ID's were mismatched.